# get mkfs.xfs options from existing xfs filesystem

Tags: mdadm, xfs, mkfs

I set up a new server last week, did some testing with different mkfs.xfs options on mdadm raid5, i finally found some statisfying mkfs options.
Now i am about to set up a new server having exactly the same disk setup
Unfortunately i did not write down the mkfs.xfs options i was using the last time, so here is my question:

Is there a way to get the mkfs.xfs options used from a running (and currently mounted) xfs filesystem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command `xfs_info` will give you something close to that. It'll dump the XFS attributes for a given file-system, which you can then map to mkfs.xfs command-options. It doesn't give you the exact flags used, but with enough parsing of the man-page you can recreate the options used for a pre-existing file-system.

```
meta-data=/dev/mapper/LVMStuff-Wibble isize=256    agcount=6, agsize=2621440 blks
         =                       sectsz=512   attr=2
data     =                       bsize=4096   blocks=15728640, imaxpct=25
         =                       sunit=0      swidth=0 blks
naming   =version 2              bsize=4096   ascii-ci=0
log      =internal               bsize=4096   blocks=5120, version=2
         =                       sectsz=512   sunit=0 blks, lazy-count=1
realtime =none                   extsz=4096   blocks=0, rtextents=0
```

A lot of these are defaults, though the value of some defaults changes with kernel and mkfs versions.